# How to fix: pivot_root Device or resource busy error

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-namespaces

I'm trying out `pivot_root` in the terminal. After creating a new mount namespace, I mounted a `tmpfs` filesystem onto `/`. Then I created a new directory and mounted a `tmpfs` filesystem onto the new directory. But when I tried to invoke `pivot_root` on the two, I received the error - `"pivot_root: failed to change root from` /' to `/tmp/new-root': Device or resource busy"`. Any idea on why this is happening? Here are the commands:

```
brianshih@brianshih ~$ sudo unshare -m
[sudo] password for brianshih: 
root@brianshih:/home/brianshih# mkdir /tmp/new-root
root@brianshih:/home/brianshih# mount -n -t tmpfs none /
root@brianshih:/home/brianshih# mount -n -t tmpfs none /tmp/new-root
root@brianshih:/home/brianshih# pivot_root / /tmp/new-root
pivot_root: failed to change root from `/' to `/tmp/new-root': Device or resource busy
```

Comment: The fact that `mount -n -t tmpfs none /tmp/new-root` succeeded seems to imply that the immediately preceding `mount -n -t tmpfs none /` didn't do what you wanted.